# Script to Change Line Color

Tags: autocad

I have a script to change the color of a line and it works great, the only problem is I only know how to get it to work with the basic colors like red, green, blue...

```
      _-color
     green

  line 0,0 0,10
```

I would like to be able use other colors for which autoCAD only gives me three numbers like (241,103,34).  Can I incorporate this into the script somehow in place of the color name?

Comment: Are those 3 numbers RGB values?

Comment: Yes, They are RGB values.  When I hover over the color I like in the color chart, those are the three numbers that are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the T for TrueColor

```
_.-COLOR
T
10,10,10
```

Last line is the RGB color

Comment: All command lines needs to be in same line when I tested it in Autocad 2019